# jQuery: looking for scrollable image showcase

Tags: jquery, slider, gallery

For a client I am looking for a specific jQuery gallery. Now I know there are tons of amazing jQuery galleries on the internet, but so far I have not exactly found what I want.

Take a look at the following gallery:

http://workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/

As you can see, there are thumbnails at the bottom. When you click a thumbnail, a bigger one shows up. However, my client wants a slider.

Like the jQuery slider:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

So basically, what my client is looking for is a combination of both. There are no transitions, and no thumbnails. It just shows ONE big photo and has a slider in the bottom. Now once you use the slider, the big photo will change into an other photo.

This will mean that the slider basically needs to be cut into pieces. Let's say there are 8 photo's, so the slider must contain out of 8 pieces (does not matter if this is visible or not).

The goal of this gallery is that my client can show multiple photo's of a specific project, a drawing for example. You start seeing the sketch of the drawing, and once you slide you see the process and finally the end result.

I have some PHP knowledge, and I can install jQuery plugins. But I have no experience in writing any functions in JS. We also do not want to use Flash.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this javascript solution that has a slider:

http://www.blueshoes.org/_bsJavascript/components/slider/examples/example2.html

As you can see a certain value is written into a textbox. I will simply remove the textbox and use the value to show specific images, etc:

image_portfolio_x.jpg

Where x is the value.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

i whipped up a demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ggTxg/1/

this should work fine

Comment: Nice demo, although not exactly what I need. When I use the slider in your demo, you can see half of the old photo and half of the newer one. What I want is that once you use the slider, it displays a new photo, not half of both. :)

Comment: well it sounds like you will have to have a custom solution written...  remember stackoverflow is not a for free work base.. I would say man up and spend 200 bucks and have someone write one for you.